# Call server side method from JSON

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services, json

How to call a method on a server side from JSON. Below is the code I am using

SERVER SIDE:

```
[WebMethod]
private void GetCustomer( string NoOfRecords)
{

    string connString = "Data Source=Something;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    SqlConnection sCon = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Sales.Customer WHERE CustomerID < '" + NoOfRecords+ "' ", sCon);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GvDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GvDetails.DataBind();

}
```

On Client Side:

```
 <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Sow Records without PostBack" />

    <asp:GridView ID="GvDetails" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


 var txtID = document.getElementById('txtValue');
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomer",
   data: "{Seconds:'" + txtID +"'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(response) {
     alert(response); 
   }
  });
</script>
```

Now I want that on button click, I would call the function at the client side [JSON], which pass the textbox value to the function.
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to re-bind the grid and have it update on the page.  The easiest thing to do in that case, is put your button and the grid in an update panel.  Give the button a server side click event.  Because it is in the update panel, it will handle the ajax call for you using ajax, and the contents of the update panel will automatically update.

If you want to do the ajax calls manuall, you won't be able to just bind the grid like that, instead you GetCustomer method will need to return something which would get used by your client javascript.  I find that rather than use $.ajax call (jquery), if you put the ScriptService tag on the method, you can make a javascript call PageMethods.GetCustomer(NoOfRecords).  The javascript call syntax is exactly like the c# syntax you declared the method with, but in javascript you add "PageMethods." in front.

Something like this:

Html:

```
<div> 
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
    </asp:ScriptManager> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" CssClass="value"></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" CssClass="buttonshow" Text="Sow Records without PostBack" /> 

</div> 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   

    //attach event to click event of button with class of 'buttonshow'.
    $('.buttonshow').click(function()
    {
        //get value of textbox with class 'value'
        var NoOfRecords = $('.value').val();

        //Call GetCustomer method, pass NumberOfRecords, and define the onsuccess and onerror functions.
        PageMethods.GetCustomer(
            NoOfRecords, 
            function(result) {
               alert('success:' + result);
            },
            function(result) {
               alert('error:' + result.get_message());
            });
    });


</script>  
<asp:GridView ID="GvDetails" runat="server"> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: hi jEREMY,

i did the same, Now I have put both button & gridview in update panel, also I have made EnablePageMethods="true", but I am getting this error
PageMethods' is undefined

Comment: With the update panel method, you don't need to enable page methods.  You don't need The [WebMethod] or the [ScriptService] attributes, and you won't need any javascript.  Just stick the button and grid in an update panel, and create a server side click event for the button that binds to the grid.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but please let me know that do I have to use JSON, JQUERY in case I don't want to use update panel.

and

Then in which case do I use JSON & JQUERY ?

Comment: If you don't want to use the update panel, you'll want to use jQuery like in my sample above, but you probably won't be able to use the GridView and bind to it.  Instead you'll probably neeed to make your GetCustomer method return some html, then use jQuery to add that html to the page.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add `ScriptService` attribute to the method. In order to pass the parameter you need to encode it as string: [3 mistakes to avoid when using jQuery with ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)